# How to retrieve a JSON Array without any property names?

Tags: c#, json, api, console

I'm new to using APIs and JSON in generall. I have made several so far for practice but have stumbled upon a this JSON file: [Link](https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories) and dont know how to retrieve it. Here's my API code.The GetCategories task is the problematic one. Thanks to anyone that takes the time to read this and help me out.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace ChuckNorris.API
{


public class ChuckClient
    {

    public async Task<ChuckNorrisJoke> GetARandomChuckNorrisJoke()
    {
        string url = $"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChuckNorrisJoke>(response);
    }


    public async Task<ChuckNorrisJoke> GetARandomChuckNorrisJokeFromCategory(string category)
    {
        string url = $"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/random?category={category}";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChuckNorrisJoke>(response);
    }


    public async Task<List<ChuckNorrisJoke>> GetCategories()
    {
        string url = $"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/categories";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChuckNorrisJoke>>(response);
    }


    public async Task<ChuckNorrisJoke> GetFreeTextSearchJoke(string query)
    {
        string url = $"https://api.chucknorris.io/jokes/search?query={query}";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ChuckNorrisJoke>(response);
    }
}

public class ChuckNorrisJoke
{
    [JsonProperty("Categories")]
    public string[] Categories { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Total")]
    public int Total { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("Result")]
    public ChuckNorrisJoke[] Result { get; set; }
    
}


}
```

Comment: That (in your link) just an array of strings, you can deserialize to a `List<string>`. Btw, dispose of those HttpClient objects, or use a static HttpClient for all.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was pretty obvious i guess. It works now. I have made a static client as well, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Jimi said. The response was just needed to be deserialized into a list.